# Error checking in script

Tags: command-line, error-handling

The error checking does not work in this case.

The directory does not exist, but cp assumes that Ubuntu_Mate_18.0 is the name of the file.

Any way to correct that?

```
cp -u -f Ubuntu_Documents.zip /media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB1/Ubuntu_Mate_18.0
if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then 
    gxmessage -fg red -font  'sans 50' -timeout 3 -geometry 1600x200 ' COPY Failed !!'
    #   echo "[Error] copy failed!" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Add a trailing `/` to the end of your path you put in there.  It should try and assume it's a directory.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I know to add a /. I just want to plan for a scenario where I accidentally left it off and the script could properly react. As it stands, if I want to copy test.zip to /fake, it creates fake instead of copying test.zip. Hope that makes sense. :-) Looks like I will just have to make sure my paths are perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following before the first line of your script:

```
[ -d /media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB1/Ubuntu_Mate_18.0 ] || mkdir -p /media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB1/Ubuntu_Mate_18.0
```

In other words make sure the directory is there before you try to copy something to it.

Comment: Well the directory is already there. Since I frequently edit my script, I want to do some error checking for all cp statements. Your addition would create a directory that already exist and which may wipe out the contents of that directory.

Comment: @fixit7 `mkdir -p` won't wipe a directory's contents.